# what are advantages and disadvantages of live click event in jquery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [event delegation vs direct binding when adding complex elements to a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827430/event-delegation-vs-direct-binding-when-adding-complex-elements-to-a-page)

what are advantages and disadvantages of jquery live click event.
its better to use click instead of live click in jquery.
live click used to tack back end process used to tack more memory space in browser.

Comment: What you are referring to is a delegated event.

Comment: This question may directly answer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827430/event-delegation-vs-direct-binding-when-adding-complex-elements-to-a-page