# removing a DOM element with jquery .remove()

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks

if we attach a delegated event with jquery .on() like

```
$(".container").on("click", "#testDiv", function (event){
  console.log(event);
});
```

and latter in the script if i remove the #testDiv element with jquery .remove() as,

```
$("#testDiv").remove();
```

then will it create any memory leak or not...

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're using a delegated event **attached to `.container`**, your event listener will **NOT** be removed.

Like [documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) says:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

This means that whenever a *click* event is triggered inside `.container`, will always execute a query to check if the clicked element is `#testDiv`

This can't be defined memory leak, because it's exactly how is supposed to work event delegation. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8827535/3611180) where is explained performance differences between event delegation and direct binding.

Anyway, if you don't need that listener anymore you can either:

- call [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function to manually remove the listener before removing the element
- or just don't use event delegation if you don't really need, but direct binding

Comment: thanks @pumpkinzzz, just one more query, in my case i have similar hundred's of event, and their respective element can be remove or added dynamically based on the user interaction. so what is the better way of handling it, should i remove the event when the element is removed and add the event back when it is added again...

Comment: @atulbajpai nope, if you have hundred of events just keep using delegated events, it's totally fine. See my updated answer